# The following classes could not be instantiated: - android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-design

I searched lot.But am not able to fix this issue.

I added both `appcompatv7` and `design` library in my project.But i am getting this error.

```
Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
```

My xml file is

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="56dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp">

            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/maitri_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <!--  Name Label -->
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
                <EditText android:id="@+id/input_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:hint="Name" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <!-- Email Label -->
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
                <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:hint="Email" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <!-- Password Label -->
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
                <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="Password"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <!-- Signup Button -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Create Account"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/link_login"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:text="Already a member? Login"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dip"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Any answers will help me.

Comment: where is `com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your app level buid.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

If using eclipse

Import design library from sdk\extras\android\support\design into eclipse workspace and mark the design project as Library by properties -> Select Android ->Check Library

Answer (score 0):

After importing design library, you need to edit project.properties file as follows:

```
# Project target.
target=android-21
android.library.reference.1=../v7/appcompat
android.library=true
```